# How to duplicate table in SQL server (include PK & FK)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How to duplicate table in SQL Server (include `PK` & `FK`), I've tried this:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

but it's doesn't work, it just copy that `columns` without `Primary Key/Foreign Key`

Comment: See this topic: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/copy-complete-structure-of-a-table

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script in my work environment to do this

This will create the following objects on the new table based on existing table

1. DEFAULT Constraint
2. PRIMARY KEY Constraint
3. UNIQUE Constraint
4. FOREIGN KEY Constraint

The tables created using `INTO` clause will not have the above objects created in new table

**Script:**

```
IF Object_id('TEMPDB..#TABLE_LIST') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TABLE_LIST

CREATE TABLE #TABLE_LIST
    (
        ORG_TABLE_NAME  SYSNAME,
        TEMP_TABLE_NAME SYSNAME
    )

INSERT INTO #TABLE_LIST
            (ORG_TABLE_NAME,
                TEMP_TABLE_NAME)
Values('old_table','new_table')


-------------------------------------------------DEFAULT SCRIPT START---------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @DEFAULT_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX) =''

SET @DEFAULT_SCRIPT = (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ['+SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID)+'].['+TL.TEMP_TABLE_NAME+']
                                                        ADD CONSTRAINT ['+replace(DC.NAME,tl.ORG_TABLE_NAME,tl.TEMP_TABLE_NAME)+'] DEFAULT '+DEFINITION+' FOR ['+C.NAME+']

                                        '
FROM SYS.DEFAULT_CONSTRAINTS DC INNER JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C ON DC.PARENT_OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
AND DC.PARENT_COLUMN_ID = C.COLUMN_ID
join #TABLE_LIST TL on OBJECT_ID(TL.ORG_TABLE_NAME) = PARENT_OBJECT_ID)

--print @DEFAULT_SCRIPT
EXEC (@DEFAULT_SCRIPT)


-------------------------------------------------DEFAULT SCRIPT END---------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------PRIMARY SCRIPT START---------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @PRIMARY_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX) =''

SET @PRIMARY_SCRIPT = (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ['+TL.TEMP_TABLE_NAME+']
                                                ADD CONSTRAINT ['+replace(TAB.CONSTRAINT_NAME,tl.ORG_TABLE_NAME,tl.TEMP_TABLE_NAME) +'] PRIMARY KEY ('+LEFT(CS.COL_LIST, LEN(CS.COL_LIST) - 1)+')

                                                '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TAB
JOIN  #TABLE_LIST TL on TL.ORG_TABLE_NAME = TAB.TABLE_NAME
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ','
                                FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE COL
                                WHERE  COL.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TAB.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                            AND COL.TABLE_NAME = TAB.TABLE_NAME
                                FOR XML PATH('')) CS (COL_LIST)
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
GROUP  BY TAB.TABLE_NAME,
                TAB.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,tl.ORG_TABLE_NAME,tl.TEMP_TABLE_NAME,
                LEFT(CS.COL_LIST, LEN(CS.COL_LIST) - 1))

--print @PRIMARY_SCRIPT
EXEC (@PRIMARY_SCRIPT)

-------------------------------------------------PRIMARY SCRIPT END---------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------UNIQUE CONSTARINT SCRIPT START---------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @UNIQUE_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX) =''

SET @UNIQUE_SCRIPT = (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ['+TL.TEMP_TABLE_NAME+']
                                                ADD CONSTRAINT ['+replace(TAB.CONSTRAINT_NAME,tl.ORG_TABLE_NAME,tl.TEMP_TABLE_NAME)+'] UNIQUE ('+LEFT(CS.COL_LIST, LEN(CS.COL_LIST) - 1)+')

                                                '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TAB
        JOIN  #TABLE_LIST TL on TL.ORG_TABLE_NAME = TAB.TABLE_NAME
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ','
                                FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE COL
                                WHERE  COL.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TAB.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                            AND COL.TABLE_NAME = TAB.TABLE_NAME
                                FOR XML PATH('')) CS (COL_LIST)
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
GROUP  BY TAB.TABLE_NAME,
                TAB.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
                CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,tl.ORG_TABLE_NAME,tl.TEMP_TABLE_NAME,
                LEFT(CS.COL_LIST, LEN(CS.COL_LIST) - 1))


EXEC (@UNIQUE_SCRIPT)

-------------------------------------------------UNIQUE CONSTARINT SCRIPT END---------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------FOREIGN KEY SCRIPT START---------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @FOREIGNKEY_SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @FOREIGNKEY_SCRIPT = (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ['+TL.TEMP_TABLE_NAME+']
                                                ADD CONSTRAINT '+replace(F.NAME,tl.ORG_TABLE_NAME,tl.TEMP_TABLE_NAME)+' FOREIGN KEY('+QUOTENAME(COL_NAME(FC.PARENT_OBJECT_ID, FC.PARENT_COLUMN_ID))+') REFERENCES '+OBJECT_NAME (F.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID)+'('+QUOTENAME(COL_NAME(FC.REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID, FC.REFERENCED_COLUMN_ID))+')

                                                '
FROM   SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS AS F
        INNER JOIN SYS.FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMNS AS FC
                        ON F.OBJECT_ID = FC.CONSTRAINT_OBJECT_ID
                        INNER JOIN  #TABLE_LIST TL on TL.ORG_TABLE_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(F.PARENT_OBJECT_ID))

EXEC (@FOREIGNKEY_SCRIPT)
```

**Note :**

1. I did not handle `schema` so script considers there is only dbo schema
2. If any `constraint` is not needed then you can comment or remove it from script.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the script is assumes constraint naming conventions, is missing check constraints, indexes, no filegroup/partition scheme, etc.  Performing this task in T-SQL requires using SQL Server catalog views instead of or in addition to INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Also, aggregate string concatenation is not reliable; use XML instead.

Comment: @DanGuzman - It is good to have same naming conventions as the base table.. Then OP asked only for `PK` & `FK` but I simply added the other constraints as well. Will update my answer for `check constraint` and `Index`. But I don't have much idea about `filegroup/partition scheme` so skipping those

Comment: @DanGuzman - Changed the string concatenation using `XML PATH` approach

Comment: The type used for table names is `SYSNAME`, not VARCHAR(200). Also, use `QUOTENAME(...)` to properly quote sysnames, don't slap rectangular brackets on yourself. (PS: I didn't downvote, nor have I tested this script).

Comment: @TT. - Updated the datatype.. Now I cannot remove square brackets so many are there;)