# Is there a way to write a sql script that copy one table from one database to another without loosing PK and FK?

Tags: sql-server, copy, primary-key, sql-server-2017

I need to move one table from one database (used for development) to another (used by user applications/the purpose of the database).

So far I do it with the *select* or *into* statement.

That works fine with just one drawback.

When doing this I lose my **primary** (PK) and **foreign keys** (FK).

Now I'm handling that by alter the tables after copying them, see the example below, but, it would be beautiful and more effective (and secure copying process) if I could do a copy of the tables with **PK** and **FK** intact all the way.

```
select *
into DB2.dbo.Ta
from DB1.dbo.Ta

alter table DB2.dbo.Ta add primary key (id)
alter table DB2.dbo.Ta add foreign key (Tb_id) references DB2.dbo.Tb
```

(Where the attribute *Tb_id* is the **PK** in table *Tb*, already existing in the database *DB2*.)

I work the Microsoft SQL server standard version 2017 and Microsoft SQL server express database engines with Microsoft SQL Studio Management version 2018.

Comment: why don't you use SSMS to script out the table and execute the script on the target database ?

Comment: I think that's part of his question @Squirrel :-) It's in the header of the question :)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194098/how-to-duplicate-table-in-sql-server-include-pk-fk) might help you.

Comment: It is possible, however for us to assist, we require all the column names you require to copy over... then we'll develop the script based on that with [`identity_insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: There is more to moving a table than just creating it with the same structure - constraints, indexes, triggers, filegroup, table options, permissions are all things you ignore (and have for years). While possible to do in tsql, it is very complicated - a task more suitable for tools that are designed to do this. A [database project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/creating-and-managing-databases-and-data-tier-applications-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) would be a far better way to manage your dbms development.